# "Target SDK" and "compile with" option missing from the "New Project" dialog box in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I downloaded the newest version of a AS from developer.android.com. Here is the version information:

`Beta 0.8.14 Build AI-135-1528390 Built on October 23, 2014`

I am watching android app development training videos in which they are also using the current version of AS.  When they click on `File > New Project`, they are getting a different dialog box than the one that I am presented with.  The one they are getting is similar to the eclipse new android project dialog boxes.  The dialog box that I am getting is missing several options such as the "target sdk" or the "compile with" options, instead it only gives me the "minimum sdk" option.  Why is this the case?

Thanks.

**I am getting this dialog box:**

[image]

**The dialog box that the instructor is getting:**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dialog box which you see in your installation was introduced in the [Android Studio 0.6.1](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio061released) and it wasn't changed a lot since then. The new project dialog which you see in your videos is from the version older than `0.6.1`.
By the way, the *newest* version of Android Studio is [0.9.3](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio093released) which can be obtained through the canary channel.

Comment: @user3249477 I have a related issue. In the manifest file, I do not see any specification for the min sdk or the target sdk. However the app compiles and runs fine in AS.  Why is this? thanks.

Comment: @Helix those are usually defined in `build.gradle`.